# Visual Studio Code JavaScript Unbound breakpoint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have not been able to debug JavaScript ever since updating VSCode to 1.63.2 and uninstalling the now deprecated Chrome debugger. I have followed the "new way" to debug in VSCode, but I must be missing something? I have spent days trying to get breakpoints to get hit, but each one displays "Unbound breakpoint". I have tried Live Server as well with no luck. I'm in crisis mode because of this built in debugger in VSCode!

I have launch Chrome in my lanuch.json
(I DO NOT use 'localhost' for the url. I develop on a machine that consists of the same environment as our production server. SSL Cert, domain, etc.)

```
{
"name": "Chrome Launch",
"type": "pwa-chrome",                       
"request": "launch",            
"url": "https://example.com/",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
"userDataDir": false                    
}
```

[image]